# How to Get line number of a word in file using ruby

Tags: ruby, file

suppose I have a file. I want to write a function that takes file and word. And returns the line numbers of that word

```
def get_line_number(file, word)
 #logic
 return line_num
end
```

Comment: Please define "line numbers of that word". What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_line_number(file, word)
  count = 0
  file = File.open(file, "r") { |file| file.each_line { |line|
    count += 1
    return count if line =~ /#{word}/
  }}
end
```

Advantage of reading line by line is when your file is too large, this wont be heavy on your resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
def get_line_number(io, word)
  io.each_line.find_index { |line| line.include?(word) }
end
```

But beware, lines are enumerated starting from 0, so if it finds a word in the first line i'll return 0. If there's no such word in the text it will return nil.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it as

```
def get_line_number(file, word)
  line_num = File.foreach(file).with_index(1) do |line, index |
    break index if line.include? word
  end
  return line_num unless line_num.nil?
end
```

Lets's test the code :

```
[shreyas@so (master)]$ tree
.
├── a.rb
└── out.txt

0 directories, 2 files
[shreyas@so (master)]$ cat out.txt
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
aaaa
[shreyas@so (master)]$ cat a.rb
def get_line_number(file, word)
  line_num = File.foreach(file).with_index do |line, index |
    break index + 1 if line.include? word
  end
  return line_num unless line_num.nil?
end

p get_line_number "#{__dir__}/out.txt", 'cc'
[shreyas@so (master)]$ ruby a.rb
3
[shreyas@so (master)]$
```